# What is Sherlock saying in Russian in Elementary episode s04e23?

Tags: translation, elementary

In *Elementary* S04E23 the following happens:

> Sherlock wonders if Moriarty tried to kill his dad to get back at him. Marcus calls and says they nabbed Krasnov. He tries to tell them he speaks no English. Gregson says he spoke just fine to the clerk at the hardware store.
>
> Sherlock asks if he thinks they’re fools. He answers in Russian and Sherlock rattles back in Russian and says they can talk in any language you like. He says he did not set off a bomb, he’s a tourist. [[Source]](http://www.celebdirtylaundry.com/2016/elementary-recap-5116-season-4-episode-23-the-invisible-hand/)

Can anyone confirm what Sherlock and Krasnov are saying? The conversation is in Russian but not subtitled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a transcription service.

Comment: @Catija We had some questions like this before and they were not closed,  see [translation tag](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation). The description of this tag says _Determining what characters said or write, or transference of a story from one languange to another._

Comment: The issue was how OP phrased the original question. And I fixed it, but based on their rude reply, I'm voting to close too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because rude op.

Comment: @cde This, however, is *not* a valid close reason and I'm pretty sure you know this very well. We are *not* voting for the user here, but for his *question*. Please don't abuse close-votes for personal vendettas or "making a point".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I speak Russian a little and I was hoping that I would be able to translate it. Your source didn't work for me, so I found a [different one](http://www.serialosy.pl/zagraniczne-seriale4/elementary/7383-elementary-s04e23-lektor-pl.html) and in this version the conversation is subtitled.

Krasnov's quotes Fyodor Dostoyevsky's short story *Bobok: From Somebody's Diary*

> Всех умней, по-моему, тот, кто хоть раз в месяц самого себя дураком
>   назовет (...)

In the [translation](http://public.journals.yorku.ca/index.php/public/article/viewFile/30255/27789) of this short story  it is translated to:

> The wisest of all, in my opinion, is he who can, if only once a month,
>   call himself a fool (...)

The translation from subtitles is:

> The cleverest of all is the man who calls himself a fool at least once
>   a month.

which is a translation of what Krasnov actually said, so it wasn't a direct quote, but a paraphrase.

Sherlock replies with a quote from Cicero:

> It is the peculiar quality of a fool to perceive the faults of others
>   and to forget his own.

Comment: Is that a full translation if the scene? It seemed longer than just that one sentence.

Comment: @cde For reason I can't explain I took only Krasov's line into account. I'll add the remaining part tomorrow.

Comment: считает, а не назовет. Krasnov's Russian is perfect, but it's impossible for me to understand what is Sherlock saying (and I'm a native speaker), I have even assumed that it might be Ukranian